# Understanding Swift/Sprite-Kit crashes

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, sprite-kit

I have built a game app with Swift and sprite kit. Most of the time everything works fine. However rarely the app crashes in a random place without a meaningful error message. Basically what I have to debug from is a piece of assembler (?) code:

[image]

Is this a bug in Swift/Sprite-Kit or is this something that I've done wrong somewhere in my code? If this is something that I can affect on, are there anytips on getting started with debugging besides starting figuring out what the piece of assembler does.

ALL HELP APPRECIATED!!! THANKS ALREADY FOR READING THIS FAR!

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS is a memory related issue. Are you using `unsafe` anywhere in your code? Without more information it's hard to be helpful... What is the full backtrace (can you see where this came from in your code)?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/debugging/

Comment: Did you add an exception breakpoint? Did you "po" the address?

Comment: No, the exception is thrown from somewhere inside sprite-kit. I don't understand what "po"ing is.

Comment: Create an All Exception breakpoint. po stands for print object. When you have a memory addres in your crash log, type po and the address. See what comes up.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the breakpoints disable or deleting and test in device sometimes the iOS simulator crashes.